# Custom class overload add functions and scope working correctly afaik, but additions not stored

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I decided today that I wanted to give my project ResponsiBlock a GUI after taking a devving break, so I've been working on that. I figured out a way to highlight and color text in the "command history" part of the program, but I wanted a way to be able to highlight text automatically when it is written, not have to specify what indices to highlight every single time. So here's an MRE of what I programmed. The `GridPosition` class is like a selecting cursor, determining where each piece of new text to highlight starts and ends. In the demo at the end of `box_print_setup()`, each style's name is supposed to be "printed" with the properties of that style, the cursor moving to its current position plus length-of-word characters. But instead, the cursor just moves to length-of-word characters as if it's adding to 0, messing up the styles putting color in the wrong places and leaving half the text untouched. But `gui['position']` is part of `gui` (global) and I think my add methods are working right...?

```
# thx GeeksForGeeks, tutorialspoint.com/how-to-highlight-text-in-a-tkinter-text-widget
import tkinter

class GridPosition:
    def __init__(self, row, column, length):
        self.row,self.column,self.length = row,column,length
    def __add__(self, other): # add and return as tkinter-readable
        not_m = self.column + int(other.split('.')[1])
        overflow = 0
        if not_m > self.length:
            while not_m > self.length:
                not_m -= self.length
                overflow += 1
        return f"{self.row+int(other.split('.')[0])+overflow}.{not_m}"
    def add_as_GP(self, other): # add and return as native format GridPosition object
        addition = self + other
        return GridPosition(addition.split('.')[0], addition.split('.')[1], self.length)
    def __str__(self): # Human-readable
        return f"GridPosition: row {self.row} column {self.column} field length {self.length}"
    def __repr__(self): #Tkinter-readable
        return f"{self.row}.{self.column}"

gui = {"position": GridPosition(1, 0, 55)}

def gui_setup(): #set up app
    global gui
    gui["rwindow"] = tkinter.Tk()
    gui["rwindow"].title("responsiblock v0.5")
    gui["rwindow"].geometry("600x600")
    gui["history"] = tkinter.Text(gui["rwindow"], width=55, height=20)
        
def box_print_setup(where):
    global gui
    codes = {"alert": "yellow/black", "warning": "orange/black", "history": "/gray", "command": "/purple", "parameter": "/violet", "debug": "/green"} # simple bg/fg pairing, automate teaching my textbox to recognize these
    # codes because there's a lot
    for i in codes.keys():
        where.tag_config(i, background=codes[i].split('/')[0], foreground=codes[i].split('/')[1])
        box_print(where, i, gui["position"], formatting=i) # show the name of each style in the corresponding style
        print(gui["position"]) # position should be 1.0, then 1.5, then 1.12, then 1.19, etc., but never changes as if gui["position"] were being initialized as a local variable. and in my own tests, the GridPosotion
        # add methods both seemed to work fine?

def box_print(where, message, pos, formatting="_"): # make a formatted message in a textbox, 
    # keeping track of what should be highlighted with a GridPosition object keeping track of the cursor. cursor-->next len(str) characters will be highlighted
    where.insert(tkinter.END, message)
    where.tag_add(formatting, repr(pos), pos + f"0.{len(message)}")
    pos = pos.add_as_GP(f"0.{len(message)}")
    
    
def main():
    global position, gui
    print("There is no actual Responsiblock code here yet, this is just a GUI test")
    gui_setup()
    box_print_setup(gui["history"])
    gui["rwindow"].mainloop()

main()
```

`gui` is already global-scoped, and if I run `addAsGP` with the following example:

```
testGP = GridPosition(2, 5, 55)
print(testGP.add_as_GP("1.51")) # "What is the endpoint of a 1-line 51-char long region starting at 2 lines and 5 chars?" (expected 4.1)
```

I get

```
GridPosition: row 4 column 1 field length 55
```

So my add methods and scoping are fine. Is there something (not so) stupid I'm missing? Please let me know. Sorry to bother you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a tag when calling `insert`. Does this solve your problem?

```
where.insert(tkinter.END, message, formatting)
```

Comment: indeed that would be simpler, yes. how did I miss that? accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `pos` in the function `box_print()` is actually a local variable, so updating it won't update the global one (`gui["position"]`). Suggest to return `pos` at the end of the function and use that returned value to update the global one:

```py
def box_print_setup(where):
    global gui
    codes = {"alert": "yellow/black", "warning": "orange/black", "history": "/gray", "command": "/purple", "parameter": "/violet", "debug": "/green"} # simple bg/fg pairing, automate teaching my textbox to recognize these
    # codes because there's a lot
    for i in codes.keys():
        where.tag_config(i, background=codes[i].split('/')[0], foreground=codes[i].split('/')[1])
        # *********************************
        # update the global variable
        gui["position"] = box_print(where, i, gui["position"], formatting=i) # show the name of each style in the corresponding style
        print(gui["position"]) # position should be 1.0, then 1.5, then 1.12, then 1.19, etc., but never changes as if gui["position"] were being initialized as a local variable. and in my own tests, the GridPosotion
        # add methods both seemed to work fine?

def box_print(where, message, pos, formatting="_"): # make a formatted message in a textbox,
    # keeping track of what should be highlighted with a GridPosition object keeping track of the cursor. cursor-->next len(str) characters will be highlighted
    where.insert(tkinter.END, message)
    where.tag_add(formatting, repr(pos), pos + f"0.{len(message)}")
    pos = pos.add_as_GP(f"0.{len(message)}")
    # ***************************************
    # return the updated pos
    return pos
```

---

Another issue in `GridPosition.__add_as_GP()`:

```py
def add_as_GP(self, other): # add and return as native format GridPosition object
    addition = self + other
    # issue: the first two arguments are strings, not integers
    return GridPosition(addition.split('.')[0], addition.split('.')[1], self.length)
```

You need to pass the first two argument as integers instead of strings:

```py
def add_as_GP(self, other): # add and return as native format GridPosition object
    addition = self + other
    row, col = addition.split(".")
    return GridPosition(int(row), int(col), self.length)
```

Comment: Oh, even though the referenced variable in
`box_print(where, i, gui["position"], formatting=i) # show the name of each style in the corresponding style` is global, the handle is local, so I need to update global differently, gotcha.